# Turn off pop-up window after downloading document

Tags: workflow, document

After I download the document using the button in document library I get this text:

> The document was uploaded successfully. Use this form to update the properties of the document.

And this window:

[image]

How can I turn it off?

Because when the pop-up appears I can't use workflow, and can't fire workflow to the element.

Comment: This window appears when you upload a document, not when you download it. It even says so in the window. "The document was uploaded successfully". You can use the multiple documents upload or you can create a custom application page for uploads.

Comment: Thanks for replay, but how could I do it ?

Comment: Which one? The custom application page?

Comment: Yeshow could I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some examples of how you can use an application page to upload a file to a SharePoint library.

You can use a form (file input) to select a file to be uploaded. Once you have the file saved to the hard drive, you can upload it to the SharePoint library.

Take a look at the links below on how to do that.

ASPX

```
    <!-- Rates Grid -->
    <div id="form">


    <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="ListBoxTable" width="100%">
    <tr><th colspan="2">Upload New Candidates</th></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlFile" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Import" runat="server" Text="Import" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <br />
    </asp:Panel>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
```

C# Code Behind

```
//Save file path
string path = "C:\\TempFiles\\" + FileUpload1.FileName;


//Save File as Temp then you can delete it if you want
FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
```

http://zimmergren.net/technical/how-to-upload-a-filedocument-using-the-sharepoint-object-model

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/602369/C-pluscodeplustoplusuploadplusdocumentplustoplus